# Handsontable - Allow sorting on specific columns

Tags: handsontable

Currently turning columnSorting to true, allows one to sort on all columns. However is there a way to specify only certain columns that can be sorted?(Or disable certain columns from being sorted)

Comment: According to the documentation, ColumnSorting plugin is not intended to do that. Asking directly on the git would be the best thing to do here. In the meantime, the only thing I can find is this "hack" http://stackoverflow.com/a/37682172/5898393

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but setting the `columnSorting` option to `headerAction: false` on the column configuration disabled the sorting for me:

```js
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    ..
    columns: [
        { data: 0, columnSorting: { headerAction: false }, },
    ],
    ...
})
```

Its also mentioned in the [docs](https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/rows-sorting/)